# How to make an Auto Typer in VB, but instead of just putting a block of text, how to type it letter by letter?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making an Auto Typer at the moment, but I find when I do it, the program just get's the text from the textbox, and just pastes it in. Instead I would like one that does a word letter by letter. Any help? Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    SendKeys.Send(BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text)
    SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")
End Sub
```

End Class

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `For Each` loop

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   For Each c as Char In BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text
        SendKeys.Send(c)
        SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ooh, so then below that, I would type: Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   For Each c as Char In BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text
        SendKeys.Send(a)
        SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")
   Next
End Sub

Comment: Just replace this with yours and tell me did you achieve what u were looking for

Comment: It works, but instead of 'C' being printed, 'BunifuMaterialTextbox2' get's printed.

Comment: Okay so let me get this straight. If I type SendKeys.Send(c), and then for example SendKeys.Send(a), is it going to do that type writer effect? In other words I just have to do that for every letter.

Comment: Suppose `BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text` contains the value `APPLE`, then this line `For Each c as Char In BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text` will pick each characters from the value of  `BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text` and store it in `c`, then this line `SendKeys.Send(c)` will pass the value of `c`, so one by one it should print `A`, then `P`, next `P`... so on

Answer (score 2):

Not actually related to the concrete problem, but here is another approach of printing letters without manually creating of `Timer` or using `SendKeys`. Possible in more readable/maintainable way

```
private async Task TypeWord(string word, int interval)
{            
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var letter in word)
    {
        builder.Append(letter);
        txtTypingTarget.Text = builder.ToString();

        await Task.Delay(interval);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it for example in button click

```
private async void btnStartTyping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await TypeWord(txtTypingOrigin.Text, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through every character in the string and passing each char to `SendKeys.Send`:

```
For Each ch As Char in str
    SendKeys.Send(ch)
Next
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm sort of new to coding. Could you maybe go through that into more detail and give me a longer example? Sorry :(

Comment: The answer @Nobody gave uses the same concept as my answer but shows how to implement it into your existing code. However, if you need more explanation, let me know.

Comment: Instead of 'C' been printed, 'BunifuMaterialTextbox2' is being printed. @Mark

Comment: Is "C" the contents of the text box? It's supposed to print the contents of `BunifuMaterialTextbox2`. You can check what the contents are by printing it to console: `Console.WriteLine(BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text)`.

Comment: Yes. It's supposed to be printing the contents of BunifuMaterialTextbox2, but I want it in a type writer sort of way, not just a block of words that get's printed, letter by letter is what I want.

Comment: That is what the for loop does. It goes through every character in the string (when you access the contents of the text box you are given a string) and passes it to `SendKeys.Send`. `ch` is a variable that holds the value of the character in the current iteration of the for loop, not literally the characters "c" and "h".